# sudo: setrlimit(8): Invalid argument

Tags: macos, catalina, sudo

After updating to Mac OS Catalina some months ago, I followed the prompted suggestions and changed my shell from BASH to ZSH.

Since that time, whenever I use sudo in Terminal, I get sudo: setrlimit(8): Invalid argument. The sudo'd command runs fine, but this error shows every time.

I don't have any plugins or modifications to my shell - it's vanilla ZSH in default Terminal.app

Can't upgrade sudo to new version. I download the file sudo-1.8.31.mac1015.pkg and install it, but remain the same version 
Sudo version 1.8.29
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.29
Sudoers file grammar version 46
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.29

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked your PATH?

I just installed sudo-1.8.31.mac1015.pkg and found out that the package installs `sudo` to `/usr/local` instead of the default `/usr`.

If you are not sure, run `which -a sudo`, the one at the top will be used. To override, just add

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

to your ~/.zshrc

Comment: @ManuelBustamante If that worked, why not consider marking this answer as accepted, so that it will help more people :-)

Comment: I had the same issue, so I also installed the newer sudo. I already had my path set to have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` and `which -a sudo` shows the new one appearing first - yet I still use the one from `/usr/bin` instead of the new one.

Comment: I ended up rebooting my mac, and now I'm getting the proper version of sudo.